# iPad custom keyboard and low memory space

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I made a custom keyboard for iOS and everything works fine but after users wrote more than 4 or 5 sentences the typing process getting slow !! here is my code :
my device is iPad 1 .

```
NSString *text = textPad.text;
    NSRange selectedRange = textPad.selectedRange;

    text =  [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:selectedRange withString:@"A"];
    textPad.text = text;
    selectedRange.location++;
    selectedRange.length = 0;
    textPad.selectedRange = selectedRange
```

I don't know what's the problem !

Comment: I don't think the problem is in this code. Is textPad a standard UITextfield or a subclass?

Comment: yes its a simple UITextView .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ARC? If not I bet that NSString just keeps building up.

```
text =  [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:selectedRange withString:@"A"] autorelease];
```

Try this. If that doesn't fix it, this definitely seems like a memory issue. Run the app in instruments with memory leak, should point you in the right direction.

Comment: `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:` already returns an autoreleased object

Comment: so what's the solution ? I analyzed the app with instruments but did not show me any specific code !

Comment: It should show you a piece of code that is being overly allocated. Use the leaks tool or the allocations tool